# how to display only the price without currency prestashop 1.6

Tags: prestashop-1.6

i'm trying to develop a prestashop theme

i did well but when it comes to the cart box i found the

```
$product_Price
```

shows me the price and the currency in one span
like

```
<span class="ajax_cart_product_txt_s">298,02 €</span>
```

needed to give the currency a special class and the price another class
so in template file i used this one

but it shows me tha price with currency

thanks in advance

Comment: What is the name of the file that contains this code?

Comment: $productPrice --> product.tpl

Comment: For me `$productPrice` returns price without currency in `product.tpl`.

Comment: can u provide ur code please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in my *product.tpl* file, I have made two different price outputs. One shows price without currency symbol,the other shows with the € symbol.

This shows € symbol (100€):

```
<span id="our_price_display">{convertPrice price=$productPrice}</span>
```

This shows just the number (100) and just currency name (not symbol, but "EUR"):

```
<meta itemprop="price" content="{$productPrice}" />
<meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="{$currency->iso_code}" />
```

I hope this helps